# Repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

What is the generic code to perform a repeated measures ANOVA?

I am currently using the code:

```
summary(aov(Chlo~Site,data=alldata)).
```

There are three different sites (Site) and four expirmental variables that I am testing individually (Chlo, SST, DAC and PAR). I am also assessing any differences in these variables and year (between 2003 and 2012):

```
summary(aov(Chlo~Year,data=year))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please read the available SO guidance about submitting a "great reproducible example". At the moment this reads like a request of an individualized tutorial on repeated measures and you show no evidence of searching SO or any other resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should avoid performing multiple calls with `aov` and rather use a mixed effects linear model.

You can find several examples in this [post by Paul Gribble](http://blog.gribblelab.org/2009/03/09/repeated-measures-anova-using-r/)

I often use the `nlme` package, such as:

```
require(nlme)
model <- lme(dv ~ myfactor, random = ~1|subject/myfactor, data=mydata)
```

Depending on the situation you may run in more complex situations, I would suggest to have a look at the very clear book by Julian Faraway *"Extending the Linear Model with R: Generalized Linear, Mixed Effects and Nonparametric Regression Models"*.

Also, you may want to ask on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) if you have more specific statistical questions.

Comment: Why do you recommend a GLM? Subsequently you show a linear mixed effects model. I recommend also reading [Zuur et al.](http://www.springer.com/life+sciences/ecology/book/978-0-387-87457-9) as it gives an easy introduction with practical examples. (And they've asked on CV already, but it seems they urgently need to solve this this weekend.)

Comment: @Roland: sorry I indeed meant a mixed effects model, thanks for spotting that, I have corrected it.

Comment: in this case, am I correct in saying that it would be:
model<-lme(Chlo~Site,random=~1|subject/Site,data=mydata) ?

Also what does subject represent in this code?

Comment: @user3170629: subject is the id of your specific subject (e.g. a patient in your study) that you made several measures on. So I would do something on the lines of `lme(Chlo~Year, random = ~1|Site/Year, mydata)`.

Answer (score 2):

The trick using `aov` function is that you just need to add Error term. As one of the [guides](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/repeated.html) says: The Error term must reflect that we have "treatments nested within subjects".

So, in your case, if `Site` is a repeated measure you should use:

```
summary(aov(Chlo ~ Site + Error(subject/Site), data=alldata))
```

Comment: Is 'subject' specific to whether it is repeat or within subjects design? If it is, does it have a code to represent those two points? I entered in the above function and I am receiving the response: object 'Subject' not found